# eth0 interface getting listed 3 times

Tags: unix, rust, wsl-2

I am on WSL 2 and using the `nix` crate in Rust and listing the network interfaces as shown below:

```rust
let ifaces = nix::ifaddrs::getifaddrs().unwrap();

for iface in ifaces {
    println!("{:#?}", iface);
}
```

When I do this, it strangely lists `eth0` three times. Once with netmask as None, and once with broadcast as None.

Anyone know why it's being listed 3 separate times? Or is it an issue with my WSL config? I'd expect it to only show up once, like in the result of running `ip show link`.

I've provided the 3 listing below.

```
InterfaceAddress {
    interface_name: "eth0",
    flags: IFF_UP | IFF_BROADCAST | IFF_RUNNING | IFF_MULTICAST | IFF_LOWER_UP | IFF_NO_PI | IFF_TUN | IFF_TAP,
    address: Some(
        SockaddrStorage {
            ss: sockaddr_storage {
                ss_family: 17,
                __ss_align: 140736544452160,
            },
        },
    ),
    netmask: None,
    broadcast: Some(
        SockaddrStorage {
            ss: sockaddr_storage {
                ss_family: 17,
                __ss_align: 140736544451856,
            },
        },
    ),
    destination: None,
}
InterfaceAddress {
    interface_name: "eth0",
    flags: IFF_UP | IFF_BROADCAST | IFF_RUNNING | IFF_MULTICAST | IFF_LOWER_UP | IFF_NO_PI | IFF_TUN | IFF_TAP,
    address: Some(
        SockaddrStorage {
            ss: sockaddr_storage {
                ss_family: 2,
                __ss_align: 94107083991267,
            },
        },
    ),
    netmask: Some(
        SockaddrStorage {
            ss: sockaddr_storage {
                ss_family: 2,
                __ss_align: 94107084128296,
            },
        },
    ),
    broadcast: Some(
        SockaddrStorage {
            ss: sockaddr_storage {
                ss_family: 2,
                __ss_align: 94107084192256,
            },
        },
    ),
    destination: None,
}
InterfaceAddress {
    interface_name: "eth0",
    flags: IFF_UP | IFF_BROADCAST | IFF_RUNNING | IFF_MULTICAST | IFF_LOWER_UP | IFF_NO_PI | IFF_TUN | IFF_TAP,
    address: Some(
        SockaddrStorage {
            ss: sockaddr_storage {
                ss_family: 10,
                __ss_align: 94107083991267,
            },
        },
    ),
    netmask: Some(
        SockaddrStorage {
            ss: sockaddr_storage {
                ss_family: 10,
                __ss_align: 94107084128296,
            },
        },
    ),
    broadcast: None,
    destination: None,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. You're not listing interfaces, you're listing interface addresses with getif*addr*. You can have multiple addresses per interface. See, e.g., how some of them have `ss_family` 2, others 10? That's IPv4 and v6 addresses. Compare with the output of `ip -brief a` or similar.

You probably want [`if_nameindex`](https://docs.rs/nix/latest/nix/net/if_/fn.if_nameindex.html) instead.

Comment: Ah cool, thank you! Do you happen to know what the `ss_family: 17` would be? Or know which man page would have that info?

Comment: No idea about a man page. [But eh](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.139/src/libc/unix/linux_like/mod.rs.html#682-720).